# Github Codespace : Running a Tkinter program

Tags: python, tkinter, github-codespaces, devcontainer

I have been programming remotely lately by using GitHub codespaces. I have been using the dev container for Python 3 to compile and run my code and it's been working just fine so far.

I currently have a program that is using the Tkinter module. I am pretty sure it has been installed correctly, but I am getting an error message whenever I am running it. I have no idea if it is even possible to run this sort of thing on a GitHub workspace.

The code I have been using is very basic Tkinter code.

**Code:**

```
import tkinter

#create main window
master = tkinter.Tk()
master.title("tester")
master.geometry("300x100")


#make a label for the window
label1 = tkinter.Label(master, text="Hello")
# Lay out label
label1.pack()

# Run forever!
master.mainloop()
```

Whenever I try running this code on a GitHub codespace with my dev container I end up getting this error message:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/compile-python/cheese.py", line 4, in <module>
    master = tkinter.Tk()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2345, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable*
```

I understand that it might not even be possible in general and that it might not be because of the way I wrote the code.

Comment: Why would you expect this to work at all?  A GUI appears on the local display of the computer it's running on - which does you no good at all when it's running on a remote server (not that a server normally even has a local display).

Comment: Well, somewhere in GitHub documentation or whatever, it said something about when running something like this the output to your code will be shown in like another tab or something after a little notification pops up in the bottom left corner. Of course, I could be wrong and have interpreted this incorrectly.

Comment: *Textual* output of your code can easily be redirected somewhere else.

Comment: I assume that this is the only type of output that can be displayed."

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/devcontainers/features/tree/main/src/desktop-lite.

Comment: I tried to connect to a port by editing my devcontainer.json file after looking at a link. But when I clicked on the globe icon in the ports view, a new tab opened in my browser with an error message that said 'This page isn't working'.